# Is it secure to put a wallet address on one's business cards as a QR code?

Tags: wallet, address-generation, receiving, address-reuse, qrcode

As a company, we're making business cards, and would like to put our bitcoin addresses on our business cards as QR codes. Yet, I know that it is a best practice for wallets to cycle addresses - I mean, after an address is used, then create another one. So, is it safe to put wallet address QR codes on multiple business cards and distribute them, and are there best practices for doing so? What security benefits does one lose by distributing the same receiving address to all clients and associates, or would it be wiser to pre-generate a few dozen each time we generate our QR codes to print business cards, so that they can all be unique? Would that even be possible, without using each one once before the next is generated?

Answer (score 2):

that's not a bad idea in regards of doing business and distributing it to people. however, as far as I know, a single address is fine because the address itself is secured. the security flaw of a single address distributed will be - people can check the addresses on how good your business is doing. hehe. correct me if I'm wrong. Wishing you all the luck with your business.

Comment: Could you please link to any more canonical sources written about this topic? As it concerns security, I would like to rely on a more comprehensively written source.